# to use a constructor or not use a constructor

Tags: javascript

I have a validator class, whose purpose is to validate input data.  Initially I wrote the class like this:

```
export class ValidatorForInputs {

  constructor(inputData) {
    this._data = inputData;
  }

  validate() {      
    let results = {};

    let validateInputDataForMissingKeys = checkInputDataForMissingKeys(this._data);
    if (validateInputDataForMissingKeys) results = { ...results, ...validateInputDataForMissingKeys };

    let validateInputDataForMissingValues = checkInputDataForMissingValues(this._data);
    if (validateInputDataForMissingValues) results = { ...results, validateInputDataForMissingValues };

    let validateInputDataMaximums = checkInputDataMaximums(this._data);
    if (validateInputDataMaximums) results = { ...results, validateInputDataMaximums };

    return results;

  }

}
```

to be called like this:

```
  let validatorForInputs = new ValidatorForInputs(inputData);
  let validationForInputsResult = validatorForInputs.validate();
// do something with validationForInputsResult
```

But then I wondered, is the constructor really necessary when the data could be passed directly to the `validate` method like so:

```
  export class ValidatorForInputs {

    validate(data) {
      let results = {};

      let validateInputDataForMissingKeys = checkInputDataForMissingKeys(data);
      if (validateInputDataForMissingKeys) results = { ...results, ...validateInputDataForMissingKeys };

      let validateInputDataForMissingValues = checkInputDataForMissingValues(data);
      if (validateInputDataForMissingValues) results = { ...results, validateInputDataForMissingValues };

      let validateInputDataMaximums = checkInputDataMaximums(data);
      if (validateInputDataMaximums) results = { ...results, validateInputDataMaximums };

      return results;

    }

  }
```

and then called like this:

```
  let validatorForInputs = new ValidatorForInputs();
  let validationForInputsResult = validatorForInputs.validate(inputData);
// do something with validationForInputsResult
```

or even called in a one liner like this:

```
let validationForInputsResult = ( new ValidatorForInputs() ).validate(inputData);
// do something with validationForInputsResult
```

With a little bit of testing, I found that the code behaves the same way.  I read the what the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) have to say about constructors but did not find any information that answers this question.

So, in a case like this, should a constructor be used or not?  If so, why?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a class provides benefits when you need *two* things:

- Persistent data associated with an instance, and
- Methods that do something with the data

If you *only* need to consolidate data in a single data structure, an object or array is simpler and more suitable.

If you *only* need to perform an operation on data and produce a result, and then have other not-very-related code work with the result, a plain function is simpler and more suitable.

Your situation looks to fall into the second category. You have data that you want to validate, but *all* you want to do is validate, and the possible `class` wouldn't be doing anything else. If all you're doing with a `class` to set a property, then retrieve that property in a method to process data, and then you never use the instance again, there's not much point to having the class at all - it's just noise. I'd use a standalone function instead.

```
export const validate = (data) => {
  const results = {};

  const validateInputDataForMissingKeys = checkInputDataForMissingKeys(data);
  if (validateInputDataForMissingKeys) Object.assign(results, validateInputDataForMissingKeys);

  const validateInputDataForMissingValues = checkInputDataForMissingValues(data);
  if (validateInputDataForMissingValues) Object.assign(results, { validateInputDataForMissingValues });

  const validateInputDataMaximums = checkInputDataMaximums(data);
  if (validateInputDataMaximums) Object.assign(results, { validateInputDataMaximums });

  return results;
};
```

Then call it like:

```
const validationForInputsResult = validate(inputData);
```

Also note that you should strongly prefer using `const` instead of `let`. `let` is a *warning* to other readers of your code (possibly including yourself, in the future) that you may be reassigning the variable in the future. If you're not going to reassign, better to use `const`, since it requires less cognitive overhead.

The `checkInput` functions and `validateInput` variables look a bit repetitive. If possible, it would be nice to change things so that they return an empty object instead of a falsey value, and have `checkInputDataForMissingValues` and `checkInputDataMaximums` return objects with `validateInputDataForMissingValues` and `validateInputDataMaximums` properties. That way, you can spread them directly into the `results` object:

```
const validate = data => ({
  ...checkInputDataForMissingKeys(data),
  ...checkInputDataForMissingValues(data),
  ...checkInputDataMaximums(data),
});
```

Having 3 separate `checkInputData` functions plus `validate` feels a *tiny* bit off to me. Organization-wise, you could consider putting them all into an object, together with `validate` if they're not used anywhere else, that way all the related functionality is in a single data structure:

```
export const validator = {
  checkInputDataForMissingKeys(data) {
    // ...
  },
  checkInputDataForMissingValues(data) {
    // ...
  },
  checkInputDataMaximums(data) {
    // ...
  },
  validate(data) {
    return {
      ...this.checkInputDataForMissingKeys(data),
      ...this.checkInputDataForMissingValues(data),
      ...this.checkInputDataMaximums(data),
    };
  }
};
```

and

```
const validationForInputsResult = validator.validate(inputData);
```

Comment: The 3 separate `checkInputData` functions were written outside of the exported entity (the class in the original code) so that they could not be accessed by anything other than the script where they were written.  The intent was to make them "private" functions.  What do you think of that approach?

Comment: Sure, that makes sense if all `checkInput` calls have to go through the main validator function.